# How can import the module yolov5 on google colab?

Tags: python, tensorflow, importerror, yolov5

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
from yolov5.models import YOLOv5

# Load pre-trained ResNet50 model
resnet_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

# Load pre-trained YOLOv5 model
yolo_model = YOLOv5(weights='yolov5s.pt')

# Define a function to preprocess the image for ResNet
def preprocess_resnet_image(image):
    resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (224, 224))
    preprocessed_image = tf.keras.applications.resnet.preprocess_input(resized_image)
    return preprocessed_image

# Define a function to preprocess the image for YOLOv5
def preprocess_yolo_image(image):
    resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (640, 640))
    preprocessed_image = resized_image / 255.0
    return preprocessed_image

# Load one of your images

resnet_input = preprocess_resnet_image(preprocessed_images)
yolo_input = preprocess_yolo_image(preprocessed_images)

# Run the preprocessed image through ResNet
resnet_features = resnet_model.predict(np.expand_dims(resnet_input, axis=0))

# Run the preprocessed image through YOLOv5
yolo_results = yolo_model.predict(np.expand_dims(yolo_input, axis=0))
```

Perform further analysis and interpretation of the results
You can extract bounding box information and class predictions from YOLO results
You can use the extracted features from ResNet and YOLO for your feeding behavior analysis

Remember that this is a simplified example and you'll need to adapt it to your specific use case.

Error I got:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-44c880d62171> in <cell line: 5>()
      3 import tensorflow as tf
      4 from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
----> 5 from yolov5.models import YOLOv5
      6 
      7 # Load pre-trained ResNet50 model

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yolov5'
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're not installed the required package (yolov5). To install yolov5 in colab follow the below command.

```
!pip install yolov5
```